# cakephp test component failed

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit

I have a site developed in cakephp with a component that I would like to test with PHPUnit.

I have create a plugin called CurrencyConverter where I have put a component into:

```
Plugin/CurrencyConverter/Controller/Component/CurrencyConverterComponent.php
```

Now I would like to test my code.

I have create a file CurrencyConverterTest.php into:

```
Test/Case/Controller/Component/CurrencyConverterTest.php
```

This is the test file:

```
<?php
class CurrencyConverterTestCase extends CakeTestCase {
    var $uses = null;
    public $CurrencyConverter;

    function testConverter() {
        $this->CurrencyConverter = ClassRegistry::init('CurrencyConverterComponent');
        $price = $this->CurrencyConverter->convert('EUR', 'EUR', '1000', 0, 0);
        echo($price);
    }
}
?>
```

If I run my test return this error:

```
MISSINGTABLEEXCEPTION
Table currency_converter_components for model CurrencyConverterComponent was not found in datasource test.
Test case: CurrencyConverterTestCase(testConverter)
```

Into my component there isn't now call to the database, how can I tell to the test to don't use model?

Or I have to create one?

Can someone explain me how to test component without using database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's wrong:

```
ClassRegistry::init('CurrencyConverterComponent');
```

Is thought to load models, it constructs a model on the fly with the given name and by convention it looks for that table currency_converter_components.

I suggest you to look at the CakePHP core tests, for example the AuthComponent tests as an example of how to instantiate components in a test.

```
$request = new CakeRequest(null, false);
$this->Controller = new AuthTestController($request, $this->getMock('CakeResponse'));
$collection = new ComponentCollection();
$collection->init($this->Controller);
$this->Auth = new TestAuthComponent($collection);
```

Your test is missing the setUp() and tearDown() as well. This doesn't look like you've read the documentation about tests. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#creating-your-first-test-case

Why is CurrencyConverter a component anyway? It deals with data, this clearly should be a model method or a behavior. Also you're missing the keywords in front of your methods and properties.

Comment: ok I know, but can you please provide a somple example for my component? because AuthComponent test is not so easy to understand and the scope of the component is totally different